# Format Royal Mail PAF

Tags: regex, string, postal-code, paf

I'm formatting addresses imported from the Sample Royal Mail PAF to Royal Mail Specification.

In the programmer's guide there are two examples with similar fields:

```
Table 8: Building Number in the Building Name field

Field on PAF                  Fictional example
Sub Building Name             FLAT 1
Building Name                 HOLLY HOUSE
Thoroughfare                  OAK AVENUE
Locality                      BIDDENDEN
Post Town                     ASHFORD
Postcode                      TN27 8B

Table 10: Address with Sub Building Name, & using a range in Building Name field

Field on PAF                  Fictional example
Sub Building Name             CARETAKERS FLAT
Building Name                 110-114
Thoroughfare                  HIGH STREET WEST
Post Town                     BRISTOL
Postcode                      BS1 2AW
```

These should  be formatted as below:

```
Flat 1, Holly House
Oak Avenue
Biddenden
ASHFORD
TN27 8BT 

Caretakers Flat
110-114 High Street West
BRISTOL
BS1 2AW
```

What is the correct logic to determine whether the `Sub Building Name` should appear on the first line with the `Building Name` or `Building Name` should be on the second line with the `Thoroughfare`?

Note that I have tested checking for a digit in `Building Name` but it fails where `Building Name` has the value `10 Sellon Court` and produces `10 Sellon Court Western Approach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer further in the documentation:

Exception Rule indicators:

i) First and last characters of the Building Name are numeric (eg ‘1to1’ or ’100:1’)

ii) First and penultimate characters are numeric, last character is alphabetic (eg 12A’)

iii) Building Name has only one character (eg ‘A’)

Comment: This probably comes a bit late, but there's a Node.js library which can parse raw Royal Mail records into formatted address lines which takes into account issues like the building exception rule. https://github.com/cblanc/uk-clear-addressing. The test suite covers all the examples in the PAF developer docs. Full Disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: Thanks Chris that looks really helpful. From my tests in the sample PAF, I found that in certain circumstances there could also be a line 4 before the post town. Did you find that in any of your tests?

Comment: Yes, found it a while back but never made it into the library. So I updated just now. It can happen with organisations with long addresses - the lib will merge the extra lines into line 3 separated with commas. I found one other edge case not listed in the docs - an address with just a sub building name. I think that one was a typo in PAF. That case has also been added as well as some performance improvements for bulk formatting.